# Return dynamic fields in tastypie GET request

Tags: python, mongodb, tastypie

Following is the resource in tastypie

```
class MyResource(Resource):
    field1 = fields.CharField(attribute='field1')
    field2 = fields.CharField(attribute='field2')

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        # Query for objects
        return obj_list
    def obj_get_list(self, request=None, **kwargs):
        self.get_object_list(kwargs['bundle'].request)
```

tastypie GET request always return field1, field2. But I have some fields dynamic in some of my records that also I want to return. How to return those dynamic fields.
I am using Mongodb as database.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic fields?

Comment: Say I have two records in mongo
1. {"title": "meetup", "message": "hello when is meetup"}.
2. {"title": "discussion", "message": "discussion on tastypie", "comments": "great"}

in above records "comments" is dynamic field so in some records it may be present or may not be present. but as I mentioned field1("title") and field2("message") in Myresource class, tastypie only return field1 and field2 even if comments is present in records so how to return all fields from records in tastypie?

Comment: What happens when you call your model like: `Foo.objects.all()`? And why are you not using `ModelResource`?

Comment: I am using Non-ORM database so using Resource instead of ModelResource